# Apple script: Change flag for message which match criteria

Tags: email, applescript

Ok, i'm creating script that should read my incoming Mail for me. 
And i stuck with one thing:
how to change flag for messages that match my criteria, cause I'm check unread message in loop, and if currently checked message match it should be flagged. It's easy to do with selected message but how to flag message in loop?

Please see my attempt:

```
if (thisSubject contains projectName or thisSubject contains projectName1 or thisSubject contains projectName2 or thisSubject contains projectName3) then
        --mark required messages with red flag
        tell application "Mail"
            #set currentMail to thisMail
            set currentMail to selection
            repeat with s in currentMail
                set flag index of s to 1 as integer
            end repeat

        end tell
```

Updated:
Here is loop that should mark all matched mails with flag

```
repeat with thisMail from 1 to count of theSubjects
set thisSubject to item thisMail of theSubjects
if (thisSubject contains searchWord or thisSubject contains searchWord2) then
    if (thisSubject contains projectName or thisSubject contains projectName1 or thisSubject contains projectName2 or thisSubject contains projectName3) then
        --mark required messages with flag  
        tell application "Mail"
            #   set allMessage to selection
            repeat with MyMessage in thisMail
                #   set read status of thisMail to true -- set read
                set flagged status of MyMessage to true -- display flag / false hide flag
                set flag index of MyMessage to 1 -- set first color for the flag (-1 remove the flag)
            end repeat
        end tell
    end if
end if
```

end repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag index defines the color of the flag. To make the flag active or not, you must use the Flagged Status.

Here is an example with read flag, and flags on/off and color

```
set projectName1 to "test1"
set projectName2 to "test2"
set projectName3 to "test3"
set SearchWord1 to "Myword1"
set SearchWord2 to "Myword2"

tell application "Mail"
set allMessage to every message of inbox whose (subject contains projectName1) or (subject contains projectName2) or (subject contains projectName3) or (subject contains SearchWord1) or (subject contains SearchWord2)
repeat with MyMessage in allMessage
    set read status of MyMessage to true -- set read
    set flagged status of MyMessage to true -- display flag / false hide flag
    set flag index of MyMessage to 1 -- set first color for the flag (-1 remove the flag)
end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: yes, thank you.
But my problem is not in flag, problem is that i cant add this flag to the mail which is now run inside cycle(loop) and which match some criteria.
I got this error:
`error  
"Mail got an error: Can’t make 1 into type specifier." number -1700 from 1 to specifier`

Comment: remove the "as integer", and then you have same code as mine...which is working.

Comment: Yes it works, but inside loop it applies only to currently selected mail, but not to one that matched criteria. Please see second code part on the question description.

Comment: I changed my first script to include your filters based on 3 possible values of project names and 2 possible values of search words. doing so, the flags are set to only message which match criteria.